Inserting attachment corrupts digital signature
I'm trying to attach an XML file to a signed PDF file in Pades.
I use iText version 8.0.3.0 to do this. (Framework 4.7.2)
Everything is fine, but the file with the attachment appears to have an invalid signature. I checked the file with Foxit, Acrobat and other online tools.
The error seems to be this:

The signature/seal is not a valid AdES digital signature!
The /ByteRange dictionary is not consistent!
The reference data object is not intact!

I read these, but they were not helpful to me.
Digital signatures invalid when I use the iTextSharp
Pdf signature invalidates existing signature in Acrobat Reader
Where am I going wrong? Here is my code:
string pdfIN = "test.pdf";
string pdfOut = "testout.pdf";

PdfReader oReader = new PdfReader(pdfIN);
PdfWriter oWriter = new PdfWriter(pdfOut);
PdfDocument oPdfDocument = new PdfDocument(oReader, oWriter);

var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfIN);

PdfFileSpec fs = PdfFileSpec.CreateEmbeddedFileSpec(oPdfDocument, bytes, "Test insert attachment", "cda.xml", PdfName.ApplicationXml, null, new PdfName("Data"));
oPdfDocument.AddFileAttachment("cda.xml", fs);
oPdfDocument.Close();


My understanding would be that adding an attachment is equivalent to mutating content. If content is mutated, the signature is void (that's the very reason to sign it in the first place). So, if you do that you have to create a new signature. I don't see this code doing that.

^^ Kind of like when you have a paper document and you sign it, if you make changes after it has been signed you need to sign off on the changes - or in some cases you even cannot make changes without commiting fraud. Just that on paper it's harder to prove.

First of all, if you want to add changes to a signed PDF, you have to use append  mode:
PdfDocument oPdfDocument =
    new PdfDocument(oReader, oWriter,
                    new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());

This makes iText append the changes as incremental update to the file (leaving the signed bytes as they were). Without this, the whole file is saved anew with changed signed bytes.
But even with this change a MDP-aware validator may reject your addition as disallowed. See this answer for an overview of allowed and disallowed changes to a signed PDF.

Thanks, I will try and write the results.

Unfortunately the signature remains invalid. I understand that the document should not be modified after signing, but adding the file is flagged and the signature becomes invalid anyway. I'm afraid there is nothing that can be done.

Is it the same error message as above or is it different now? (It should be different with append mode, in particular it should not mention ByteRange issues anymore.)

now the message is: The document contains undefined object modifications after the signature revision! But the signed It seems valid with the tools but not with Foxit and Acrobat Reader.

I just found out that this procedure corrupts the Xml attachment and makes it unreadable, as if it were encrypted. I don't know how to show it to you here.

"The document contains undefined object modifications after the signature revision!" - Hhmmm, undefined object modifications looks like an euphemism for "the validation code is unable to analyze the change".

"I don't know how to show it to you here." - Please share the PDF file itself, before and after the change. You can share it using e.g. a publicly accessible file on google drive, dropbox, or a similar service (please nothing that drowns the downloader in ads or requires the downloader to create an account) and posting the URL here.

This is the pdf file with valid signature but without attachment:
https://www.gesconweb.it/temp/test.pdf
This is the pdf file with unreadable attachment and signature not recognized (by Acrobat and Foxit):
https://www.gesconweb.it/temp/testout.pdf
Thank you for your patience.

"This is the pdf file with unreadable attachment" - Hhmm, the attachment is readable. It only is not a XML file (in spite of its name) but the original PDF again. But that also is clear from the code you show: you add the bytes you read from pdfIN as attachment.

"and signature not recognized (by Acrobat and Foxit)" - well, in both cases you can select "View Signed Version" from the context menu to see the signed revision, and in both cases the signature in the signed revision is ok. Apparently, therefore, adding file attachments after signing is disallowed. (You might want to try adding the file attachment using a file attachment annotation; changing attachments is allowed in your file after all. But probably the validators will still complain about the attachment itself, even if not about the annotation.)

You're right, I didn't realize that, I'm stupid. Now I'll check everything and write the results here.

Perfect! The attachment is intact, the signature is recognized only by some tools, but it is not a big problem. Many thanks.
